# How to add gravity for button CompoundDrawable in android?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

I am developing android application with some custom views. Here i am adding buttons with CompoundDrawable in one of my view. Here i am giving CompoundDrawable for buttons to give bullets effect for the text. But i am facing problem with CompoundDrawable alignments.
If my button text is single line then alignment is showing good. Button text is more that 2 line that will show my bullet in incorrect place. At any way i would like to show my bullet CompoundDrawable at left-top of my button text.

Here is my button creating code

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(myParams);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableId, null, null, null);
button.setBackgroundResource(0);
button.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP);
```

But it is not showing my button what i would like to show.
I have attached image of my buttons. On that 1 is proper. but i would like to show 2, 3 also same like button 1.
Please look on attached image.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not code it in XML?

Comment: i am getting button text from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of [android layouts](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/)........

Comment: for ex: having relative layout as parent can have buttons or any widgets to follow parent layout....